# How to connect local server to GCM client application?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have built a `GCM application` and a `local server in PHP`. I want to store the registration ID of the client into the server database. I am running the server on localhost. I tried to use `IPv4` address like `192.168.x.y/gcm/save.php`*(It's running fine and it's identifying all files in `C:/wamp/www` when it is run on my computer)* and connected both my local computer and the android application to the `same wifi network` but it isn't working. How can I send my RegId to the local server running on my computer? Here is the `Utils.java` file:

```
public class Utils {

static Context context;
public static final String TAG = "Utils";
public static final String UserName = "UserName";

public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";

public Utils(Context context) {
    Utils.context = context;
}

public SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences() {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(((ActionBarActivity) context)
            .getClass().getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
    Log.i(TAG, key + " : " + value);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getFromPreferences(String key) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
    String value = prefs.getString(key, "");
    if (value.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, key + " not found.");
        return "";
    }
    return value;
}

String getRegistrationId() {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
    String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION,
            Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion();
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

static int getAppVersion() {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}

public void storeRegistrationId(String regId) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences();
    int appVersion = Utils.getAppVersion();
    Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
    Log.i(TAG, "Reg ID : " + regId);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
    editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
    editor.commit();
}

public String getCurrentIPAddress() {
    //return "http://192.168.1.37/safety_app/save_reg_id.php";
    return "http://192.168.14.198/safety_app/save_reg_id.php";
}

public void showToast(final String txt) {
    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

}
```

And here is `sendRegistrationIdtoBackend` function:

```
public void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {

    Log.i(TAG, "sendRegistrationIdToBackend");

    Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                httppost = new HttpPost(utils.getCurrentIPAddress());

                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                        user_name));

                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reg_id", regid));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                utils.showToast("reached 6");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                utils.showToast("reached 7");
                Log.i(TAG, "Response : " + response);
                utils.showToast("reached here");

                if (responseBody != null) {
                    utils.showToast("reached nn");
                    if (responseBody.equalsIgnoreCase("Username already registered")) {

                        utils.showToast("Username already registered");

                        hidePB();

                    } else {
                        if (responseBody
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("New Device Registered successfully")) {

                            utils.savePreferences(Utils.UserName, user_name);
                            // Persist the regID - no need to register
                            // again.
                            utils.storeRegistrationId(regid);

                            utils.showToast("Device registration successful");

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    setPeopleList();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                utils.showToast("catch-"+e.getMessage());
                //showPB("catch-"+e.getMessage());
                Log.d(TAG, "Exception : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();

    }
```

Here is my `save_reg_id.php`:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "safety_app";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$name = $_POST["username"]; // = "VVV";
$reg_id = $_POST["reg_id"]; // =         "APA91bEfFaXquuolftF0jy55C5LShdL5Ugu5NrSk_bmwd8wpYW6Ht4dKW5gEq2WFuMFRQD2LOVRF7kN7CtJrh-cTRwXxtELSfUSi4W8L56bi35vYWvylRwZA0qZ02qv9GFYshQENn6Xv-s3yW5sLoaxl-Hka5ZzFuIZBNpiCVQqseG20ckH0e10";

$duplicate_check_sql = "SELECT * FROM registereddevices where username =      '$name'";
$suplicate_result = $conn->query($duplicate_check_sql);

if ($suplicate_result->num_rows > 0) {

   echo "Username already registered";

}else{

$sql = "INSERT INTO registereddevices (username, reg_id) VALUES ('$name', '$reg_id')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New Device Registered successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

}    
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Can you try pinging your server from another device on the network? Or, try accessing a page on the server from your device's web browser. This is just to make sure the server is actually reachable.

Comment: Also check that your HTTP port is set to 80.